# color change over multiple lines of aligned equation

Tags: math-mode, color, draft

I want to be able to generate my document in two different levels of detail.

1. (When `draft` is not set): normal version
2. (When `draft` option is used): more detailed version. Some calculations include extra steps to make it more easy to follow. The additional lines should be colored differently (gray).

I came up with my own `explain` command for this. Its argument should only be shown when `draft` is set and should be set with gray color.

However in the MEW below this is not working.

```tex
\documentclass[
    % draft,
]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ifdraft}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\explain}[1]{%
    \ifdraft{%
        \textcolor{gray}{%
            #1%
        }\ignorespaces%
    }{}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{aligned}
            {(a + b)}^2
            \explain{%
                &= (a + b)(a + b)\\
                &= a^2 + ab + ba + b^2\\
            }
            &= a^2 + 2ab + b^2
        \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The example fails to compile when `draft` is used.
It seems my use of `\textcolor` is not valid since it spans over the alignment character `&`.

How could I change my new command to make this work?

Ty,
Franz

Comment: If you're latex is fully up to date, then it is not `\textcolor` it then `&`'s, they are now hidden so deep that `aligned` cannot see them. And just using `\color{gray}` does not work either as it never penetrates into the next cells and thus does nothing after the first `&`.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain in better detail what exactly the end goal is with this.

Comment: I want to be able to generate the document in two different levels of detail. One with just the first line ({(a + b)}^2) and the last line  (&= a^2 + 2ab + b^2) and the other one with the additional steps in between. The additional steps should be colored gray if they are present. I want to use the draft option to toggle between the versions.

Comment: Explain it in your question.

Comment: ok. it should be more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot format multiple cells (anything delimited by `&` or `\\` inside the `aligned` environment) at once. You can, however, style the contents of every cell individually. So, the following would be possible:

```
\documentclass[
    draft,
]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ifdraft}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\explain}[1]{%
    \ifdraft{#1}{}%
}
\newcommand{\explaincolor}{%
    \ifdraft{\color{gray}}{}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{aligned}
            {(a + b)}^2
            \explain{
                & \explaincolor = (a + b)(a + b) \\
                & \explaincolor = a^2 + ab + ba + b^2 \\
            }
            & = a^2 + 2ab + b^2
        \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With the `draft` option disabled, you would get:

[image]

---

With the above in mind, you could try to automatically insert the relevant color after every `&` and after every `\\` (except if nothing follows at the end of the argument) that appears inside the argument of `\explain` (additionally once at the very beginning of the argument to cover the first cell). I am unsure, however, whether this won't break something in certain circumstances:

```
\documentclass[
   draft,
]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ifdraft}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \insertexplaincolor } { m } {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__myexplcol_explcolbody_tl { \explaincolor #1 }
    % add \color macro after every occurance of &
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \& } { \& \c{explaincolor} } \l__myexplcol_explcolbody_tl    
    % add \color macro after every \\
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \c{\\} } { \c{\\} \c{explaincolor} } \l__myexplcol_explcolbody_tl    
    % remove \color macro after \\ if occuring at the end of the string (ignoring whitespace)
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \c{\\} \c{explaincolor} \s* \z } { \c{\\} } \l__myexplcol_explcolbody_tl    
    \tl_use:N \l__myexplcol_explcolbody_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\explaincolor}{\color{gray}}

\newcommand{\explain}[1]{%
    \ifdraft{\insertexplaincolor{#1}}{}%
}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{aligned}
            {(a + b)}^2 
            \explain{
                & = (a + b)(a + b) \\
                & = a^2 + ab + ba + b^2 \\
            } 
            & = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 
        \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: well ... that's annoying. Especially if I move lines into or out of the additional explanations. I admit it is a solution though.

Comment: @Franz I added another solution that automatically inserts the color macro. But handle this approach with care. It might break in certain circumstances.

Comment: haha ok I don't even remotely understand how this works ... but it does. I will use it and see how far it gets me in other situations where I want to add stuff.

I thought NewDocumentCommand need the xparse package but even that seems to be wrong. Could explaincolor not be removed and color{gray} be inserted directly?

Comment: @Franz You can replace `\c{explaincolor}` with `\c{color}\{gray\}` in the `\insertexplaincolor` macro. I thought it would be nice to have the color definition somewhere else ... =)

Comment: turns out that some use cases for my original definition of `explain` now do not color the text correctly anymore. I guess that was to be expected. I started a new question for this here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/658973/using-the-explain-command-of-657851-for-text-and-equations) maybe you want to take a look?